# Creating new User Routines in Talend Open Studio

Tags: data-migration, talend

I have created a new user routine in Talend Open Studio but I am not able to view the newly created user routine in any of the function lists.

Comment: Take a look into this link : http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-code-routines-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The function will show up if you document your function as javadoc.

Example:

```
 /***** 
 * helloExemple: Print the hello message on the console
 * {Category} xpto
 * {talendTypes} String
 *
 * */
```

You can see more examples in the project `TALENDDEMOJAVAS -> pasta t03_demoroutines ->  demo03_tmap`